# Relabel mini Environment of Optidef Package into optimize

Tags: environments, optidef

I'd like to define a new environment called `opti` that works the same like `mini` environment but replaces the word 'minimize' into 'optimize'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, you can copy the definition of the `mini` environment from the package's .sty file to your preamble and modify it accordingly. Note that there are separate definitions for `mini*`, `mini!` and `minie`.

(I don't know whether the abbreviation "opt" makes any sense in this context.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{optidef}

% modification of mini environment
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{opti}{D||{\defaultProblemFormat} O{\defaultConstraintFormat} D<>{} m m m m}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{b}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{s}}%
    % Short version problem
    {\setFormatShort{opt}{#4}\BaseMiniStar{#2}{#4}{#5}{#7}{opt}{#3}}%
    % Long version problem  
    {\setFormatLong{optimize}{#4}\BaseMiniStar{#2}{#4}{#5}{#7}{optimize}{#3}}%
}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{s}}%
    % Short version problem
    {\setFormatShort{opt}{#4}\BaseMini{#2}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{opt}}%
    % Long version problem  
    {\setFormatLong{optimize}{#4}\BaseMini{#2}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{optimize}}%
}%
}%
{\endBaseMini\toggletrue{bodyCon}}

\begin{document}

\begin{opti}
{w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x)}
{\label{eq:Example1}}{}
\addConstraint{g(w)}{=0}
\addConstraint{n(w)}{= 6}
\addConstraint{L(w)+r(x)}{=Kw+p}
\addConstraint{h(x)}{=0.}
\end{opti}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely beautiful answer.

Comment: Can you do the same for 'mini!' environment and replace it with 'opti!'? My goal is to label the equations.

Comment: I found it:\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{opti!}{D||{\defaultProblemFormat} O{\defaultConstraintFormat} D<>{} m m m m}{%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{s}}%
 % Short version problem
 {\setFormatShort{opt}{#2}\BaseMiniExclam{#2}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{opt}{#3}}%
 % Long version problem 
 {\setFormatLong{optimize}{#2}\BaseMiniExclam{#2}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{optimize}{#3}}%
}{\endBaseMiniExclam\toggletrue{bodyCon}}

Comment: The definition of the `mini!` envrionment is right after the defintion of the `mini` environment in the `.sty` file. Just copy it from there to your preamble and replace the relevant parts.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper Habicht, this is precisely what I did following your previous solution.